# Load Large Excel Files in Databricks using PySpark from an ADLS mount

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

We are trying to load a large'ish excel file from a mounted Azure Data Lake location using pyspark on Databricks.

We have used pyspark.pandas to load and we have used spark-excel to load, not with a lot of success

##### PySpark.Pandas

```
import pyspark.pandas as ps
df = ps.read_excel("dbfs:/mnt/aadata/ds/data/test.xlsx",engine="openpyxl")
```

We are experiencing some conversion error as below

```
ArrowTypeError: Expected bytes, got a 'int' object
```

##### spark-excel

```
df=spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel") \
        .option("header", "true") \
        .option("inferSchema","false") \
        .load('dbfs:/mnt/aadata/ds/data/test.xlsx')
```

We are able to load a smaller file, but a larger file gives the following error

```
org.apache.poi.util.RecordFormatException: Tried to allocate an array of length 185,568,653, but the maximum length for this record type is 100,000,000.
```

Is there any other way to load excel files in databricks with pyspark?

Comment: Please refer to the issue - https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel/issues/557 - there seems to be some work arounds mentioned there - also since it is a xlsx file - suggest trying out the option `.option("maxRowsInMemory", 20) // Optional, default None. If set, uses a streaming reader which can help with big files (will fail if used with xls format files)` some comments seem to point to it providing better results. Hope this helps...

Comment: This definitely helped thanks!!

Comment: Glad it was useful...

Answer (score 1):

In your Excel file, there's probably some kind of weird format, or some kind of special character, that is preventing it from working. Save the Excel file as a CSV file, and re-try. You should easily be able to load a CSV file, because it has no weird things of any kind, whereas Excel has all kinds of weird things embedded in it.